# Как получить список всех сборок проекта?

Tags: c#, winforms, дизайнер

Пытаюсь написать редактор для свойства нетривиального контрола.

Встала задача получить список всех сборок, собираемых из проектов текущего решения. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` не годится, так как не всегда возвращает все сборки.

Answer (score 2):

*Боюсь, вам придется точнее сформулировать вопрос.*

Вы говорите, что хотите получить список сборок, **собираемых из всего `solution'а`.**

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` позволяет получить список текущих **загруженных** сборок в рантайме вашего приложения, и это совершенно никак не соотносится со сборками, собираемыми из некоторого абстрактного `solution'а`.

---

Так вот, в случае, если вам нужны все текущие сборки, которые отреференсены вашим текущим приложением, то воспользуйтесь примерно следующим методом, модифицировав его рекурсивно, если необходимо *(отмечу, что он **прогружает все сборки**, что может быть нежелательно)*:

```
  var mainAsm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
  yield(mainAsm);

  foreach (var refAsmName in mainAsm.GetReferencedAssemblies())
  {
      yield Assembly.Load(refAsmName));
  }
```

---

В случае, если я понял вас неправильно, и вам просто нужны имена всех сборок (`Class libraries`), собираемых из текущего `solution'а`, то распарсите файлы `.vcproj`, отделите те из них, которые действительно собирают `.dll'ки` и выцепите их имена.

Сделать это *(с учетом `xml` формата файлов проекта)* должно быть достаточно тривиально.

Comment: При работе в дизайнере `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` возвращает что-то не то.

Comment: @Modus Как вы вызываете код в дизайнере?

Comment: Ещё раз. Я разрабатываю нетривиальный контрол. Что касается runtime, то с ним всё в порядке. Но у этого контрола есть свойство, которое требуется устанавливать в дизайнере формы, на которую оно положено. Для редактора этого свойства требуется получить список всех сборок в Solution.